# How to handle a Web Browser back and forward navigation in a Wp7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using a web-browser in my windows phone 7 application.
I just want to know that how to handle its back and forward navigation just like any desktop browser.
And also how to block a particular navigation.

I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100538/handling-hardware-back-button-and-sending-it-to-webbrowser-control-running-on-wi) and many others but couldn't find anything working for me.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work like a desktop browser you can implement a `stack`.

You will put two buttons back and forward. As the user navigate to next **URL** in browser you push them into **history stack** and when he wants to get back by pressing back button you navigate to the first url in the history stack programmatically and pop it up from the **history stack** so he can navigate back till stack has some **URLs** in it. Similarly for forward you push **URLs** into **forward stack** as he navigates back and and whenever he presses forward button you navigate to first element in **forward stack** and pop it up and so on till you have urls left in **forward stack**. Once he navigates to some url which is not navigated from **forward stack** by you then you empty the forward stack and fill it again when he moves back.

This way you can even show history urls in a list or however you like.

About navigation cancel, here is the code from the link to question in the comments under your question, it should work.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    //cancel navigation
     e.Cancel = true;

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can cancel navigation by handling the OnNavigating event

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    //cancel navigation
     e.Cancel = true;

}
```

To go back, you can execute javascript on the page.

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval","history.go(-1)");
```

and move forward:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval","history.go(1)");
```

If `eval` is blocked on the page, [this site](http://javascript.about.com/library/bleval.htm) might be useful for alternatives. Don't forget to set [webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to `true`.

Comment: I want to Stop navigation on click my Stop button
How to call this?

Comment: For whatever reason, the `Stop` method that is on a WinForm's WebBrowser control has been removed from `Silverlight`. I don't think there's a direct way to immediately stop all pending navigation. As a hack, which I haven't tried, you could disable then reenable the WebBrowser control. Or, you could just reload the page the user is currently on. Another option could be to handle Javascript's `onUnload` method but I don't know if that would work or not.

Comment: I use history.go for back and forward, it works very well but i cant realize does it possible to go back or not!(for disable or enable the Back or Forward button)

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611834/change-a-c-sharp-variable-with-invokescript

Comment: FYI: merged into this question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625037/how-to-do-stop-back-and-forward-with-webbrowser-in-wp7

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer will work, but you can make a workable solution even simpler, since the WebBrowser control has an internal navigation stack.

Add forward and back button controls to your UI.  In the action routine for each of them:

```
private void forwardButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            WebBrowser editWB = sender as WebBrowser;
            if (editWB != null && editWB.CanGoForward)
                editWB.GoForward();
}
```

You can get fancier: in the `WebBrowser.LoadComplete` event (not the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event), you could test .CanGoForward and .CanGoBack and selectively enable or disable the buttons appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the idea proposed by BobHy but failed as in my WP7 / VS2010 Express I did not find the method CanGoForward for WebBrowser. I am using it inside of a canvas in user control which might impact the experience.

However, I found a straight forward detailed example at http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/WebBrowser_Control_Techniques_in_Windows_Phone implementing a stack as suggested by Parveen that works for me fine.